# Amazon dynamically changing the name of their CSS slectors and HTML objects?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I built an Amazon.es web scraper using Selenium

I'm using a CSS selector to find the total number of pages (to determine how many times my loop will iterate.)

But everyday, I have to go back and update the selector name because it seems to change dynamically.

I'm not extremely good with HTML/CSS, how do they do this?

Selector that worked yesterday:

`lastPage = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.s-desktop-width-max.s-desktop-content.sg-row > div.sg-col-20-of-24.sg-col-28-of-32.sg-col-16-of-20.sg-col.sg-col-32-of-36.sg-col-8-of-12.sg-col-12-of-16.sg-col-24-of-28 > div > span:nth-child(5) > div.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row > div:nth-child(58) > span > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(6)')`

Selector that works today:

`lastPage = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.s-desktop-width-max.s-desktop-content.sg-row > div.sg-col-20-of-24.sg-col-28-of-32.sg-col-16-of-20.sg-col.sg-col-32-of-36.sg-col-8-of-12.sg-col-12-of-16.sg-col-24-of-28 > div > span:nth-child(5) > div.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row > div:nth-child(51) > span > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(6)')`

Comment: Amazon reputedly pushes numerous updates every minute. As you've found, these css selectors may change at any time are not reliable ways to drill down. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, the Amazon API is likely a better solution than web scraping. https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But, You can use regular expression by using xpath.

```
    Syntax
    -//tagName[contains(@attribute,’value’)]
```

Comment: I tried using XPath, but I didn't know you could use contains inside it.

I came up with an alternative solution since using `browser.find_elements_by_class_name`.

My intention was to extract an integer from the last clickable page to know how many times I had to iterate my loop. However, your answer is valid and I will mark it as the solution!